# Sort data from database to select correct listView android

Tags: android, date, listview, android-tabbed-activity

I have an app where I can create some lessons (English,French,...). Those lessons have a beginning and end of date. I store the selected Dates as a String in my database.

I'd like know to create a TabbedActivity with 3 tabs ( Past/Current/Futur).

Past would contain all the lessons where the end of date is before the current date.Current would contain all the lessons where the current date is between the beginning and the end of the 2 dates. And Futur would contain all the lessons where the beginning date is after the current date.

But, since I store them as String values, is that possible ? If yes, can you explain me how ?

I can post some code if you need (I'm not posting code right now because idk if its possible what i'm asking).

Thank you guys!

@update with method in helper

```
 public Cursor getCoursFuture()
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = c.getTime();
    String currentDate = df.format(date);

    String query ="select ID as _id, branche_cours, designation from "+TABLE_COURS+" where date('"+COLONNE_DATEPREMIER+"') > '"+currentDate+"'";
    Open();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

My SimpleCursorAdapter

```
    lvCours =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListCours);
    final Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getCoursFuture();
    String[] from = { "branche_cours", "designation" };
    int[] to = { R.id.text_branche_cours, R.id.text_designation };
    lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
    lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Just store your dates as a UTC timestamp.  Storing dates as Strings just causes unnecessary headaches

Comment: how do Ii do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to sort by date

Lets say your the current date is `currentDate`;

You can sort using this query for choosing future lessons

`select *  from Table where date(dateColumn) > currentDate`

Replace `>` with `<` and `=` for other queries.

Edit : 
 When you call c.getTime() , you get a date Object. You need to format it into a String.

```
Date date = c.getTime(); 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String currentDate = df.format(date);
```

Comment: but those queries, I write them in my DatabaseHelper or in that tabbedactivity ?

Comment: And how can I convert those String in DateTime values ? Can you please show me an example of the method for one of the ListView (let's say the Past)=

Comment: and btw , dateColumn on my db is a string column ... Should i first convert all the values in datetime and then insert it, or can I write it like you said, even if it's a String value ?

Comment: You don't have to convert it date time and then insert it. 
As long as the String is a valid date , SQlite will convert it it date .

Comment: Can you check my question (I updated it) ? Also, it's a Cursor method because I use simplecursoradapter, but is it like this that I should do ? And I store in the format "dd.MM.yyyy"

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Can you check my method again please ? I've changed again. Is it correct now ?